# How do I do HQL join for many-to-many associations in GORM in test environment?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have the following domain classes (`Product`, and `Tag`) with many-to-many relationship:

```
class Product {

    static belongsTo = Tag

    static hasMany = [tags: Tag]

    String name

    Set tags

}
```

and

```
class Tag {

    static hasMany = [products: Product]

    String tag

    Set products

}
```

Every time I run the following HQL, I get nothing:

`select p from Product p join p.tags t where t.tag like '%'`

I'm sure there are data in the datastore since if I change the structure such that the association is one-to-many (`p.tag` instead of `p.tags`), my test passes.

Comment: Have you tried the query without the where clause? To focus on the join first.

Comment: Yes, and still returns nothing. It just doesn't return anything when I start joining.

Comment: I know you mentioned you have matching data, but a one-to-many uses different tables. With a many-to-many you'll have a third table: the join table. Are all three tables populated with the appropriate data.

Comment: Actually that is one of the things I'm curious about. I don't know what Grails does in the background and how the tables look like when I run the tests. I can confirm that the data are set up correctly because when I do `findAll` and check the associated objects, they're there.

Comment: With a many-to-many the join table contains two columns: the primary keys of the domain classes being joined. For example, your join table has the columns `product_id` and `tag_id`. Hmm... what happens when you do this: `select p from Tag as t join t.products as p`

Comment: Still nothing. I wonder if it's got something to do with the code running in test environment.

Comment: It could be. What you can do is run the Grails console in dev, create some instances, and then run the query.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it's due to the code being run in test environment. The HQL query works in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is not so much that the query is invalid; the HQL query works as expected. The problem, however, is that the code I'm using to check the query is being run under Grails' test environment. By default, the GORM used in that environment isn't properly configured to support HQL and other String type queries. The test code has to be set up such that Grails uses the right GORM when running it.

In summary, here are the things I did to resolve the issue (I'm running this in Grails 2.5.x):

1. annotated the test class with `@Domain([Product, Tag])`
2. annotated the test class with `@TestMixin(HibernateTestMixin)`

For more information, check [the official Grails documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.0/guide/single.html#unitTestingDomains).

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
Product.findAll 'from Product where tags.tag like ?', [ '%something' ]
```

Comment: `tags` is a collection so Hibernate throws an exception saying there's an illegal attempt to deference it.